# Is it possible to access variables of child class in parent class in java?

Tags: java

```
class Parent
{ //need to access variable of child class
}

class Child extends Parent
{ int a=10;
}
```

Comment: no. This is not possible without a great deal of reflection and generally a bad idea.

Comment: The parent should never have any dependence or even knowledge of child classes. Period.

Comment: This is a clear indication that your design is wrong.

Comment: From a technical perspective I'd see this question as a challenge, from a design perspective ....oh boy :)

Comment: Lets say you are creating method in Parent class which will be inherited by Child class, and it should be able to use some field from that Child class. Why not declare such filed in Parent class in the first place? If you can't then how should your method react if it will be inherited by child class which will not have such field?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to know about the child some how - either through design or discovery using reflection.

This example depends on "a" being "package" or "public" and not "private".

```
public int getChildA() {
    int a = 0;
    if (this instanceof Child) {
        a = ((Child)this).a;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really must, what you need to do is try to get the field with reflection and catch the possibility that the field is not found. Try something like:

```
static class Parent
{ 
    public int getChildA(){
        try {
            Class clazz = Child.class;
            Field f = clazz.getDeclaredField("a");
            if(!f.isAccessible())
                f.setAccessible(true);
            return f.getInt(this);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
            //the parent is not an instance of the child
        } catch (SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SOtests.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return -1;
    }
}

static class Child extends Parent
{
    int a=10;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Child c = new Child();
    Parent p = (Parent) c;
    System.out.println(p.getChildA());
}
```

the output is `10`, however this is still a really bad idea from a design prospective. I also had to make the classes for the demo but you can change them back without a problem.